# React state updates without Re-render like Discord Video Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-hooks

For events like `onpointermove` is it possible to update some value in DOM without causing a re-render?  The value needs to be updated dynamically but without causing the re-render. Just like how it is done in discord video, I hover over the SeekBar and I see a time tag, Which doesn't re-render.

To emulate I opened a Video in **Discord Web** with React Dev Tools, which shows that the tag doesn't re-render. I can see the changes being made in DOM like **Style** and **Value** which aren't cauing the element to re-render but only on actions like `mousedown` etc are shown. Even there isn't any `onpointermove` event attached to any of those children on which I am hovering. Here is the link to [preview video.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rqdz8padhgi0v4m/chrome_dRuchvmrFH.mp4?dl=0)

I have created something similar like discord however in my case the hover component is re-rendering as I change the hover position Here is the link to [Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-herschel-htsdx0?file=/src/Hover.jsx) of this. Please ignore the functionality might have some errors but is the exact same scenario. Here is the link to my original [deployed version](https://limeplay.me/) and here is the link to [preview video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fvtfipov8ns9xfc/chrome_Vw6hzTwXNd.mp4?dl=0) of my version.

I tried looking into Discord's styling and the obfuscated code but couldn't find anything useful. Can it be some hacky CSS way? Various other ways like memoization definitely won't work since the state is being updated.

Comment: I feel if you're using a state variable. it won't be possible but for your scenario, have you tried using a normal variable whose value is updated eveytime the state of the seek bar changes?

Comment: Hi! I doubt if that works in React. Normal variables don't notify the Real DOM about the changes and values being updated and as I checked it doesn't. I am not sure if there is any way to update some value in DOM without using states. Still wondering how discord did that.

Comment: Yeah but as i said, you can manually update the seek bar if you wrap that variable in a useEffect for a state vairable right?

Comment: Hi! @Sampurna Sorry, I didn't got that you mean creating a `ref` and storing the value in it and adding that `ref` in useEffect dependency? But that will also cause a re-render right?